# How can I add test folders in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, testing

I am working on a project in which the test folders were removed and I want to do a unit test. 
Is there a way to create the test folders again for this project?

Comment: did you refer docs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below are the steps to add your **test folders** on **Android Studio 3.1.2** on **Macbook** :

1. Right click on **app** > **New** > **Folder** > **Java Folder**
   [image]
2. On Configure Component window check **Change Folder Location** checkbox
   [image]
3. Change the location to **src/test**
   [image]
4. Your **test** folder will be created under **src** folder i.e. same place where previous **test** folder was

Comment: it didn't work for me that directory folder, it worked with:  /src/test/java/, more info about the process in:    https://developer.android.com/studio/test

Comment: after following these instructions, the Android view shows a new folder called "java" underneath my existing "java" folder. so it goes app -> java (blue) -> java (green) -> package -> class. I am not sure how to rectify this as the structure does look correct on the filesystem (src/main/java and src/test/java)

Comment: further update to above: after following these instructions, Android Studio automatically added a `sourceSets` entry to my build.gradle, which caused the above issue. I removed the `sourceSets` block and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 19):

For those who have already created folders with test classes, you can mark its directory as "Test Sources Root". Just click Right-Mouse-Button on the directory, then *Mark Directory as/Test Sources Root*.

[image: AndroidStudio Test Sources Root]

Comment: i can not find that option

Comment: I checked on Android Studio 4.1 and 4.2 and it's there. I have such subfolders tree: `app/src/ [ androidTest/java | main/java | test/java ]` 1st and 3rd should be marked by default as "Test Sources Root", 2nd as "Sources Root".  I don't see this option for packages inside "Sources Root" - what you probably have tried.

Answer (score 11):

1. Switch to Project mode

[image]

2. Right click: module -> New -> Directory

[image]

3. On the pop-up menu, select `src/test/java`

[image]

4. Now you will be able to see the test dir has been created

[image]

You will now be able to use `OPTION + T` to generate tests from intended classes, and it will be automatically placed in the correct dir + package

Comment: Right click on src folder and select create directory and android studio will show you folder like "test/java", "test/kotlin", "androidTest/java" etc. Just select one, simple.

Answer (score 6):

On Android Studio click on src->new->Directory 
Name it test then right click on test-> new-> Folder->Java Folder 
Name it java

You'll end up with this structure :

```
 src/test/java
```

In case you don't have the JUnit dependencies you can add them :

```
dependencies {
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```